# iOS app: screen size coding ignored when reload data happens for table view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm having a problem with coding for different screen sizes.  I'm programmatically checking to see what the screen size is and then adjusting a table height if the bigger screen is detected, otherwise the layout is set for a standard iPhone layout.  The bigger screen size is detected and the table size is adjusted properly.  When I do a 'reloadData' on the table the view reverts to the smaller size table.  The size check code is stepped through, but seemingly ignored?  When I switch to another tab and then return to the tab in question, the screen redraws with the bigger size table.  Below is the code I use for the screen check and some screen shots showing the changing table sizes.  There is too much code to post everything.  Thanks in advance, Any thoughts out there?

```
-(void)screenCheck
{
    // detecting screen size
    if (([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2) && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568))
    {
        // retina 4" screen
        // changing table height
        tableVerseView.frame = CGRectMake(tableVerseView.frame.origin.x, 215, tableVerseView.frame.size.width,260);
    }
}
```

[image: screen shot]

[image: screen shot]

** section where the code is called.  There are many others, mainly every time a 'reloadData' is executed

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // reloading table data
    [self loadVerses];
    [self.tableVerseView reloadData];

    // testing for no verses available
    if ([tableVerseData count] > 0)
    {
        // selecting the previously selected table row
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:array_pos inSection:0];
        [tableVerseView.delegate tableView:tableVerseView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        // clearing table view because there are no verses left
        labelVerseText.text = @"You need to add a new Verse to your 'New Verses' Challenge List.";
        labelVerseTitleOpen.text = @"Verse Title";
        labelVerseDaysOpen.text = @"Day Count";
    }

    // screen resolutution check
    [self screenCheck];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you're calling `-screenCheck`?

Comment: added a code example under the screen shots